# Solve a limit for two variables ($1^\infty$)

Tags: limits

I want to solve this limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (\infty, 1)} (1+\frac{1}{x})^{\frac{x^2}{x+y}}$$

I've got to this point:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (\infty, 1)} (e)^{(\frac{x^2}{x+y}) \ln {(1+\frac{1}{x})}}$$

Which means I only have to solve this one:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (\infty, 1)} (\frac{x^2}{x+y}) \ln {(1+\frac{1}{x})}$$

But how? I am stuck.

Comment: The correct answer (according to WolframAlpha) is $e$.

Comment: try l' hopital rule

Comment: There are two variables. How?

Comment: change double limit to repeated limit

Comment: That only seems to work in case I know both the limits exist. Anyway, we haven't been taught that (yet?) so I would rather not use it.

Comment: ok, maybe  write the nominator as $\dfrac {x^2-y^2+y^2}{x+y}$ then, use the definition of e directly

Comment: Yes, that works. Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: write $\dfrac{x^2}{x+y} = x\left(\dfrac{x}{x+y}\right)$,and the answer should be $e$ because $\dfrac{x}{x+y} \to 1$ when $x \to \infty, y \to 1$ .

Comment: But it still is $0\times\infty$, isn't it?

Comment: I've grown to understand this answer. It is not that clear, but nevertheless it is the correct solution. I am gonna mark it as such.